# HTML Email Template Content Between Header/Footer Issue

Tags: html, css, email, whmcs

I understand this is probably something really simple but I don't know anyone that can help me with my issue except the awesome Stack Overflow community. I have not worked with HTML/CSS to this extent for a while.

I am trying to create a new, better looking email template for my business. First I was having an issue with WHMCS where the global CSS styling wouldn't work. So to get around that I have been using inline CSS in the footer and header sections (see below):

[image: WHMCS Email Settings]

The issue I am now having is the header and footer seem to be separated, and in the middle, where I want the email content, there is nothing but white space, even if I type text in there. I would like the middle content section to follow the styling above and below so it looks seamless and so that text can be typed in there.

Here is the code for both the header and footer (big space between two):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset={$charset}" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table data-module="header" class="email_table currentTable" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="box-sizing: border-box;border-spacing: 0;mso-table-lspace: 0;mso-table-rspace: 0;width: 100%;min-width: 100%!important;">
<tr>
<td class="email_body email_start" data-bgcolor="Body" style="box-sizing: border-box;vertical-align: top;line-height: 100%;text-align: center;padding-left: 16px;padding-right: 16px;padding-top: 32px;background-color: #dde5ee;font-size: 0!important;">
<!--[if (mso)|(IE)]><table width="800" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="vertical-align:top;width:800px;Margin:0 auto;"><tr><td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;"><![endif]-->

<div class="email_container" style="box-sizing: border-box;font-size: 0;display: inline-block;width: 100%;vertical-align: top;margin: 0 auto;text-align: center;line-height: inherit;max-width: 800px!important;">
<table class="content_section" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="box-sizing: border-box;border-spacing: 0;mso-table-lspace: 0;mso-table-rspace: 0;width: 100%;min-width: 100%!important;">
<tr>
  <td class="content_cell header_c brt pt pb" data-bgcolor="Content" data-border-top-color="Accent" style="box-sizing: border-box;vertical-align: top;font-size: 0;display: inline-block;width: 100%;text-align: center;background-color: #ffffff;border-top: 4px solid #2376dc;border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;padding-top: 16px;padding-bottom: 16px;line-height: inherit;">
    <!-- col-6 -->

    <div class="email_row" style="box-sizing: border-box;font-size: 0;display: block;width: 100%;vertical-align: top;margin: 0 auto;text-align: center;clear: both;line-height: inherit;max-width: 600px!important;">
      <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]><table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="vertical-align:top;width:600px;Margin:0 auto;"><tr><td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;"><![endif]-->

      <div class="col_6" style="box-sizing: border-box;font-size: 0;display: inline-block;width: 100%;vertical-align: top;max-width: 600px;line-height: inherit;">
        <table class="column" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="box-sizing: border-box;border-spacing: 0;mso-table-lspace: 0;mso-table-rspace: 0;width: 100%;min-width: 100%!important;">
          <tr>
            <td class="column_cell px pt_xs pb_0 logo_c tc" data-color="Content" data-link-color="Accent" style="box-sizing: border-box;vertical-align: top;width: 100%;padding-top: 8px;padding-bottom: 0;font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size: 16px;line-height: 100%;color: #616161;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;text-align: center;padding-left: 16px;padding-right: 16px;min-width: 100%!important;">
               <a href="#" data-color="Accent" style="text-decoration: none; line-height: inherit; color: rgb(35, 120, 220);"><img src="https://hypeservers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Logomakr_0tDvse-2.png" width="110" height="24" alt="Hype Servers" style="max-width: 168px;outline: none;border: 0;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;clear: both;line-height: 100%;height: auto!important;" /></a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
            <td valign="top" class="bodyContent" style="box-sizing: border-box;vertical-align: top;font-size: 0;display: inline-block;width: 100%;text-align: center;background-color: #ffffff;line-height: inherit;">
              <p>'Hello'</p>
            </td>

      <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->


<!-- </table> -->
<!-- </div> -->
<!--[if (mso)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->

<!-- </td> -->
<!-- </tr> -->
<!-- </table> -->





</table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table data-module="footer_center" class="email_table" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="box-sizing: border-box; border-spacing: 0; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; width: 100%; min-width: 100% !important;"><tr><td class="email_body email_end" data-bgcolor="Body" style="box-sizing: border-box; vertical-align: top; line-height: 100%; text-align: center; padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 16px; padding-bottom: 32px; font-size: 0 !important; background: #dde5ee;" align="center" bgcolor="#dde5ee" valign="top">
<!--[if (mso)|(IE)]>
<table width="800" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="vertical-align:top;width:800px;Margin:0 auto;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">
<![endif]-->
<div class="email_container" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; display: inline-block; width: 100%; vertical-align: top; text-align: center; line-height: inherit; max-width: 800px !important; margin: 0 auto;" align="center">
<table class="content_section" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="box-sizing: border-box; border-spacing: 0; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; width: 100%; min-width: 100% !important;"><tr><td class="content_cell footer_c py bt brb" data-bgcolor="Accent" data-border-top-color="Default" style="box-sizing: border-box; vertical-align: top; font-size: 0; display: inline-block; width: 100%; text-align: center; border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px; padding-top: 16px; padding-bottom: 16px; border-top-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-top-color: #d7dbe0; line-height: inherit; background: #ffffff;" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" valign="top">
        <!-- col-6 -->
        <div class="email_row" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; display: block; width: 100%; vertical-align: top; text-align: center; clear: both; line-height: inherit; max-width: 600px !important; margin: 0 auto;" align="center">
        <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]>
<table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="vertical-align:top;width:600px;Margin:0 auto;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">
<![endif]-->
          <div class="col_6" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; display: inline-block; width: 100%; vertical-align: top; max-width: 600px; line-height: inherit;">
            <table class="column" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="box-sizing: border-box; border-spacing: 0; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; width: 100%; min-width: 100% !important;"><tr><td class="column_cell tc pb_0" data-color="Footer" data-link-color="Footer Link" style="box-sizing: border-box; vertical-align: top; width: 100%; padding-top: 16px; padding-bottom: 0; font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif !important; font-size: 16px; line-height: 23px; color: #999999; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; text-align: center; min-width: 100% !important;" align="center" valign="top">
                    <p class="fsocial" data-color="Footer" style="font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif !important; font-size: 16px; line-height: 100%; color: #999999; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; display: block; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 16px;">
<a href="#" style="text-decoration: underline; line-height: inherit; color: #999999; display: inline-block;">
</a>
   <a href="#" style="text-decoration: underline; line-height: inherit; color: #999999; display: inline-block;">
<img src="http://www.stampready.net/dashboard/editor/user_uploads/zip_uploads/2017/07/16/HZUKBlFvVrCsqQm6I51iRE7A/stampready_template/images/twitter_64_dark.png" width="24" height="24" alt="" style="max-width: 24px; outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; clear: both; line-height: 100%; height: auto !important; border: 0;" /></a>
   <a href="#" style="text-decoration: underline; line-height: inherit; color: #999999; display: inline-block;">
</a>
</p>
                    <p data-color="Footer" style="font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif !important; font-size: 16px; line-height: 23px; color: #999999; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; display: block; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 16px;">
                      ©2017 Hype Servers<br />
                      3000 Fake Address Way, Fake Town 736278.                 </p>
                    <p data-color="Footer" style="font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif !important; font-size: 16px; line-height: 23px; color: #999999; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; display: block; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 16px;">
                      You are subscribed to Hype Servers Mailing List. <a href="#" data-color="Footer Link" style="text-decoration: underline; line-height: inherit; color: #999999; display: inline-block;">
<span data-color="Footer Link" style="text-decoration: underline; line-height: inherit; color: #999999;">
Unsubscribe</span>
</a>
                    </p>
                  </td>
                </tr></table></div>
        <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<![endif]-->
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr></table></div>
<!--[if (mso)|(IE)]>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<![endif]-->
</td>
</tr></table></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the body copy text is not visible to you because it's been styled with font-size:0px;

You can't rely on CSS to work in emails like it would on the web so make sure you do all your styling inline (as you have done).

I'm not familiar with WHMCS so forgive me if I've got the wrong end of the stick here.